# Display table contents in UI

Tags: database, user-interface, h2, udb

Is there any tool which shows the H2 or UDB DB table contents in UI. I dont want to run the query to see the contents of the table.This is more like the Presentation of the tables in UI. Also I dont want to use any Db consle.Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Use java -cp h2-1.4.187.jar org.h2.tools.Server or you can also use org.h2.server.web.WebServlet and configure a path